# Nav Bar not Hiding with react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, nav, react-context

I have two navbars in my site. One is only displayed on small screens with a media query which is the one I am having issues with. I have a react context that controls the visibility of both navs with the same boolean variable when a slideshow is displayed. When the slide show is displayed I want to hide the navs. The large nav has this functionality, but the small nav never shows. Before adding this react context the navbar would display as normal but now it is never displayed.

**small navbar render:**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div id="initialImage">
          <div className="d-fixed d-md-none">
            <DisplayContext.Consumer>
              {(context) =>
                context.state.isNavVisibile ? (
                  <nav className="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
                    <button
                      className="navbar-toggler"
                      type="button"
                      data-toggle="collapse"
                      data-target="#navbarToggleContent"
                      aria-controls="navbarToggleContent"
                      aria-expanded="false"
                      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                    >
                      <span></span>
                      <span></span>
                      <span></span>
                    </button>
                    <div
                      className="collapse navbar-collapse"
                      id="navbarToggleContent"
                    >
                      <ul className="navbar-nav">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                          <a
                            className="nav-link text-white font-weight-bold"
                            href="#vintage"
                          >
                            Shop Vintage 
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                          <a
                            className="nav-link text-white font-weight-bold"
                            href="#e"
                          >
                            Shop Euiubi
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                          <a
                            className="nav-link text-white font-weight-bold"
                            href="#about"
                          >
                            A Message from the Creator
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                          <a
                            className="nav-link text-white font-weight-bold"
                            href="#"
                          >
                            Contact
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </nav>
                ) : null
              }
            </DisplayContext.Consumer>
          </div>
          <Navigation />
          <div id="titles" className="clearfix greeting"></div>
          <ScrollAnimation />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Display Context:

```
export const DisplayContext = createContext();

export class ContextProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    isNavVisible: true,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <DisplayContext.Provider
        value={{
          state: this.state,
          hideNav: () =>
            this.setState({ isNavVisible: !this.state.isNavVisible }),
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </DisplayContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**on click handler to open and close slideshow**

```
  toggleSlideVisibility = () => {
    const dcontext = this.context;
    dcontext.hideNav();
    this.setState({ slidesVisible: !this.state.slidesVisible });
  };
```